# Under Mobile Data- System Services what is Software Updates doing exactly, even though I have updates disabled?

Tags: ios, software-update, cellular-data

It has used about a MB of data in the past few days. Yet I have all automatic downloads disabled, and all update downloads over mobile data off as well. Is it just consuming this data checking for updates, or what?

Answer (score -1):

There’s a lot of things using data, quite a list actually.

Settings -> Cellular -> Cellular Data: System Services >

Tap on the System Service >

You only have 1 MB?

Here's mine (1.5 GB):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ok..... this doesn't have anything to do with my question. Software updates doesn't even appear in this image.

Comment: Scroll down further it’s there.

Comment: You do realise you can't scroll down in the original picture you posted, right?

Comment: That’s why I posted a second screenshot scrolled down. The OP needs to scroll down on their screen. This shows everything using cellular data. 

Comment: I am OP. What do you mean I need to scroll down. I can see where software updates are on my system services. I don't see what this has to do with my question?

Comment: It's showing mobile data use. In relation to your question. Apple is still using cellular mobile data wether you like it or not. It's likely  security updates on iOS to avoid malware issues. Much like gatekeeper and XProtect blocklist updates on macOS. Blocking known threats.